# Git hub error for rails_tutorial_sublime_text settings

Tags: git

In trying to follow these instructions for a Ruby on Rails tutorial:

https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_sublime_text

When I issue:

```
git clone git@github.com:mhartl/rails_tutorial_sublime_text.git
```

I get this error:

```
Cloning into 'rails_tutorial_sublime_text'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you don't have a proper ssh key for accessing mhart's repositories using githubs private clone urls.

You might want to try `git clone git://github.com/mhart/rails_tutorial_sublime_text.git` instead.

If you want to read more about how ssh keys work, and how to use them to access github, the github help pages are really good.

- [Github SSH help articles](https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles)